# Twitter Bootstrap on Mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

So I have a website that is built on bootstrap (Navigation + Body Container) so everything should be responsive.

I have everything in rows and columns (col-lg-12).

So my question here is this. I have my body container column size as (LG - Large (incase anyone gets confused with the phone's))

When I access this website from my computer and I resize the screen, it works as expected, pretty good. (Since I followed a tutorial)

But when I access the website from my mobile phone, the website looks like what I would see on a full screen PC screen.

I looked online and an article said to use two classes for the DIV's inside the ROWs. So this is what I did.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">Content!</div>
```

This also doesn't work. How would I go on to making my bootstrap more mobile compatible as it does when I resize my browser?

Do I have to make the website redirect to a mobile version when accessed on mobile like most websites? Or do I have to include a certain meta tag in my head?

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your `<head>`?

Comment: I don't at the moment, I'll try it out and tell you the result. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Many thanks it worked! Could you post this as an answer and give source so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you don't have the viewport meta tag in your `<head>` which tells the browser to use the device's width as the html document's width. See the [basic template docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the source with the best answer I needed!

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake.